# How to navigate a website by clicking buttons on other page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new here. Just want to know if my idea is possible. What I want to do is:

1. There is 2 pages, 1st page is for the buttons(next and prev) and the other one is for the presentation.
2. I have many hidden divs on the presentation page where in when I click the next button the next div will be visible and when I click the prev buttton the prev div will be visible and other divs are hidden.
3. I think you got the idea.
4. It's like a powerpoint Presentation but I don't want my buttons to be seen by the audience so I moved it to a different page but it is connected to the presentation page which is the one who will be controlled by the buttons.

I lost my code before but I'll try to remake it again. I'm Willing to learn new languages if needed, what I have knowledge are php, js, html, css

Comment: it is, look at [messaging events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event).

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean,

There are three methods you can use to achieve this:-

1. Easy Method
2. Hard Method(But this will give you what you are looking for)
3. A Better way(will give you what you are looking for)
4. Advanced Method(from the comments by Stephen P)

## Easy Method:

The easy method would include rechanging your setup, you don't need to have your buttons in another page(we will talk about this in the hard method).

Instead, rechange your idea and design to use your keyboard buttons to switch from one div to the next. You can use event listeners to listen for your keyboard arrow keys to switch back and forth with different divs(Use ai to give you boilerplate code).

## Hard Method:

This will get you exactly what you are looking for.

You will need to have good knowledge about these provided below:

- Websockets(you can use socket.io)
- Backend( I recommend node.js with express.js)

You can setup a backend to be the main gateway to implement the buttons to sent a req to the server api and then use websockets to connect to the presentation layer.

## The Better Method(Not best practice, but would get the job done if you are not a developer)

This could mean the presentation page constantly checking the state of the application. You would need to know about state management tool and have to change the value back and forth.

And the presentation page would sent request recursively(consistently every 2-5 seconds) to see the state. If the state says "next" then the presentation will move to the next.

However, this is not professionally recommended for big applications like when you work in big tech companies. But if you are a kid, and what to implement this idea. This could be the most practical way.

### Advanced Method(from the comment section from Stephen P)

> If you're going to do polling instead of websockets you would want to  do long
> polling where you do a fetch from an api url and just wait for it to
> complete, telling you 'forward' or 'back' or whatever. That will
> eventually time-out so you check the response object and retry if the
> fetch completed because of a timeout. This gist has a basic outline of
> handling a failed fetch, with some discussion following it. –  Stephen
> P

Comment: Constantly polling is not a "better method", and you certainly wouldn't do it _recursively_.  If you're going to do polling instead of websockets you would want to do _long polling_ where you do a fetch from an api url and just wait for it to complete, telling you 'forward' or 'back' or whatever.  That will _eventually_ time-out so you check the `response` object and retry if the fetch completed because of a timeout. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/odewahn/5a5eeb23279eed6a80d7798fdb47fe91) has a basic outline of handling a failed fetch, with some discussion following it.

Comment: Hello Stephen,
You are right however from what I understand, the person is looking to get his project done, learning node.js or web sockets just to get his presentation wouldn't be practical.

 I did mention above-- if you are little kid and want to get the job done(who doesn't understand software engineering) if this is just your presentation. I also mentioned this method is not professionally recommended above.

He just seems to understand the fundamentals of software engineering. I called it the "better method" as in everything inside the method above would be of his caliber
Thank you

Comment: True Micheal, I should delete that and rephrase, maybe as "Advanced Method" (unless you want to add it to your answer)

Comment: sure I will add it!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, on your phone you need to have a page for managing the presentation site, which is open on your PC.

To do this, you need to configure the backend using a programming language. This server will handle web socket connections between devices.

You can first try to start learning node.js, which will help you with this

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. I have two examples.

1. Browser storage
   You could use your browsers local storage to make this. But you need to have two displays displaying two different browser windows from the same browser. Now when you update the local storage (e.g. `localStorage.setItem("page", 5)`), you'll just need a listener on the other browser tab.
2. API
   You could make a simple API, which is probably the best option. But again you will need two browser tabs and two displays. One tab on the display for your audience and one on yours. When you click on the button for the next side, your browser sends a signal to your api. this api stores this information. The tab for your audience could call this api a couple of times a second and do something with the return.

hope I could help out :)